# Locking SDL Window Position Using Python

Tags: python, window, pygame, sdl

I'm building a game using Pygame, which is built upon SDL, and I was wondering if there was a way to lock the position of the game window, such that user cannot move the window by grabbing the top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SDL2 ;
First, you get the current position of the window starting position, at the start of your main loop. You can get the position by using this function :

SDL_GetWindowPosition(SDL_Window *window, int *x, int *y)

With this you will get the starting position of your window.

Second, you catch the SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MOVED event (That event is from SDL_WINDOWEVENT). When you catch that event, just override the new position with :

SDL_SetWindowPosition(SDL_Window *window, int x, int y)

You can consult the SDL2 doc here : http://wiki.libsdl.org/

More specific : http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowPosition and
http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowPosition

But, if pygame use SDL 1.2, I don't think it's possible to do this, because this function wasn't present before SDL 2.

EDIT : As I can see, pygame was updated with SDL2, so these functions are supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Create the window with the flag `pygame.NOFRAME` like so:

```
pygame.display.set_mode(resolution, flags=pygame.NOFRAME)
```

Relevant docs: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html